# Problems loading resources from function C++/SFML

Tags: c++, linker, sfml, undeclared-identifier

I have a stucture that I use to declare Textures, Sprites, Music, Fonts,  Sounds, etc in a header. I then use a corresponding .cpp file to set said textures to their corresponding sprites, and so on.

I have created the struct object in main, and called the function. But When I build my program, I get a million "undeclared identifier" errors. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

resources.h:

```
#ifndef __SFML__resources__
#define __SFML__resources__

#include "SFML/Audio.hpp"
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

struct resources
{
float opacity = 1.0;

sf::Texture texturePlayer;
sf::Texture textureSettingsMenu;
sf::Sprite spriteSaveMenu;
sf::Sprite spriteSettingsMenu;
//start screen texture
sf::Texture textureStart;
//gamestate background sprite
sf::Sprite spriteScreen;
sf::Font font;
sf::Font font2;
int loadResources();
// hundreds more lines of declarations below
//...
};
#endif
```

resources.cpp:

```
#include "resources.h"


int resources::loadResources()
{
if (!textureSaveMenu.loadFromFile("images/magicmenu3.png"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;


if (!textureSettingsMenu.loadFromFile("images/inventorymenu.png"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

spriteSaveMenu.setTexture(textureSaveMenu);
spriteSettingsMenu.setTexture(textureSettingsMenu);

if (!textureStart.loadFromFile("images/skyocean.png"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

if (!font.loadFromFile("fonts/arial.ttf"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

if (!font2.loadFromFile("fonts/dominican.ttf"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;

if (!musicBattle.openFromFile("audio/musicBattle.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicBattle.setVolume(20);
musicBattle.setLoop(true);


if (!musicOpening.openFromFile("audio/maintheme.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicOpening.setVolume(30);
musicOpening.setLoop(true);

if (!musicDefeat.openFromFile("audio/defeat.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicDefeat.setVolume(50);
musicDefeat.setLoop(true);

if (!musicForest.openFromFile("audio/forest.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicForest.setVolume(10);
musicForest.setLoop(true);

if (!musicWorldMap.openFromFile("audio/bluefields.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicWorldMap.setVolume(40);
musicWorldMap.setLoop(true);

if (!musicVillage.openFromFile("audio/welcomehome.ogg"))
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
musicVillage.setVolume(40);
musicVillage.setLoop(true);

//every single declared resource is set within this function
//but the function is too large to display fully here
}
```

main.cpp:

```
 #include "SFML/Audio.hpp"
 #include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
 #include <iostream>
 #include "random.h"
 #include "player.h"
 #include "entity.h"
 #include "projectile.h"
 #include "enemy.h"
 #include "textDisplay.h"
 #include "pickup.h"
 #include "wall.h"
 #include "sword.h"
 #include "npc.h"
 #include "battlemenu.h"
 #include "cursor.h"
 #include "name.h"
 #include "itemshop.h"
 #include "characterselection.h"
 #include "mainmenu.h"
 #include "exp.h"
 #include "drops.h"
 #include "weaponshop.h"
 #include "armorshop.h"
 #include "startmenu.h"
 #include "room.h"
 #include "resources.h"


int main()
{
//create the main window
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(720, 500), "Sky Ocean");
window.setFramerateLimit(60);
window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

//View
sf::View view1(sf::FloatRect(200, 200, 300, 200));
view1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(window.getSize().x, window.getSize().y));
view1.setCenter(sf::Vector2f(view1.getSize().x / 2, view1.getSize().y / 2));
window.setView(view1);

//load resources
struct resources resources1;
resources1.loadResources();

//class object
class player Player1;
Player1.sprite.setTexture(texturePlayer);

class player Player2;
Player2.sprite.setTexture(texturePlayer);
Player2.rect.setScale(1.6, 1.6);
Player2.sprite.setScale(1.6, 1.6);

//...
}
```

Comment: "#define \_\_SFML\_\_resources\_\_" - Don't use reserved names in your own code. Any symbol starting with underscore followed by a capital letter and any symbol containing two underscore characters in succession are reserved for the implementation and must not be used in your code.

Comment: why is it a bad thing to do this, is it what is causing my error? what would be the correct way to name it? What's the difference?

Comment: It is not what is causing your current problem. I just thought I'd let you know.  It is bad since such names are officially reserved and thus your names may clash with names used by your compiler or standard library. It is also in some cases undefined behaviour to `#undef` such names and there are other potential headaches. So I just wanted to say, "don't use reserved names" :-). Since you asked; personally I'd probably have named that header guard "MY_PROJECT_SFML_RESOURCES_H" if "sfml_resources.h" was the header it was protecting.

Comment: How are you building your program? What IDE or commandline?

Comment: Do you tell your compiler where to find the SFML headers?

Comment: I am using visual studio 2013

Comment: I don't think I tell the compiler where to find them, I #include the headers from the files inside my project folder

Comment: Is the SFML library installed in the default place?

Comment: Did you try using angle brackets `<SFML/Graphics.cpp>` rather than quotes?

Comment: Just tried angle brackets, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: SFML library is installed in the right place, I previously had all of these declarations inside of main and it worked just fine

Comment: Why do you initialize the resources in a function and not the constructor? You should use RAII. Also, lines like `setTexture(texturePlayer)` are wrong. You should use `setTexture(resources1.texturePlayer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you to read [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224537/c-c-header-and-implementation-files-how-do-they-work) about header files.

---

`resources.h` indeed doesn't contain declaration of identifiers used.

You will have to `#include` header file which contains those declarations so compiler will be able to see them. Please read [SFML declaration](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/modules.php) to see which modules need to be included and `#include` them into **header file**, now you're including them only into `main.cpp` so only `main.cpp` contains declaration of identifiers. When compiler reads `resources.cpp` it doesn't see those declaration, hence`undeclared identifier` error.

resources.h for example should look like this:

```
//...

#include "entity.h"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <Whatever.hpp>

struct resources
{

//...
```

Comment: I've already tried this where I include the sfml/graphics.hpp inside of resources.h to no avail

Comment: `#include` header files in every file where they're needed (whether it's source or header file).

Comment: @anarchyistheanswer in `entity.h` you probably missed something (`Audio.hpp`?), but as I wrote "#include header files in every file where they're needed (whether it's source or header file)"

Comment: Even when I include these inside of resources.h the identifiers are still undeclared, I updated my answer to show what i'm talking about

Comment: The compiler says that each occurrence of the declared textures, sprites, fonts, etc inside of the struct are undeclared. When it comes across texturePlayer inside of main() for instance, texturePlayer is undeclared

Comment: I'll bet that `texturePlayer` was declared in `entity.h` which is not included in `main.cpp`. `#include` header files everywhere where needed.

Comment: nope, texturePlayer is declared inside of resources.h and I updated the `#include` headers inside main to be exactly what is in my program. Also I edited resources.h to show clearly that texturePlayer is declared

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115906/discussion-between-pcaf-and-anarchyistheanswer).